# How to get all tables of a MSSQL-Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm coding a tool to count all entries in a table. My question is, how can I get all the tables of an existing database? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and I already have a method to get a string array of a table:

```
List<string> lResult = new List<string>();
        SqlConnection sqlConn10 = new SqlConnection(sConnStr);
        sqlConn10.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlComm10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + sColumn + " FROM " + sTable + " WHERE " + sWhere, sqlConn10);
        SqlDataReader myReader10 = sqlComm10.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            while (myReader10.Read())
            {
                lResult.Add(myReader10.GetString(0));
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            myReader10.Close();
            sqlConn10.Close();
        }

        return lResult.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use the sql-command

```
select * from sys.tables
```

or you use a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = SQLConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` has a lot of useful metadata about your database.

Answer (score 1):

to get the list of all tables you need to use a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
```