# Getting all Table name in a database with c#

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, getschematable

I am using **VS2010 , .Net 4.0, MS SQL SERVER 2008**.

I thought I know how to get all table names from a Database. But I was wrong. With table names, I get View names as well as. But when i do it for Views, I just only get Views. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is my code, what I have tried:

```
    public DataTable getAllTables(string serverName, string dbName, string authenticationType, string Login, string pass)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = Return_Conn(serverName, dbName, authenticationType, Login, pass))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            DataTable dt = sqlConn.GetSchema("Tables");
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            string[] column = { "TABLE_NAME" };
            dt1 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable("dd", false, column);

            sqlConn.Close();
            return dt1;
        }
    }

    public DataTable getAllViews(string serverName, string dbName, string authenticationType, string Login, string pass)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = Return_Conn(serverName, dbName, authenticationType, Login, pass))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            DataTable dt = sqlConn.GetSchema("Views");
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            string[] column = { "TABLE_NAME" };
            dt1 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable("dd", false, column);

            sqlConn.Close();
            return dt1;
        }
    }
```

in **`DataTable dt = sqlConn.GetSchema("Tables");`** this line, **dt** contains all tables along with views. and in dt, **table_type** for **Views** are showing **"View**" and for **table**, showing **"Base Table"**.

but in **`DataTable dt = sqlConn.GetSchema("Views");`** this line, **dt** contains only views.

What is wrong here?How could I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate query

[How to get all tables of a MSSQL-Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517991/how-to-get-all-tables-of-a-mssql-database)

Comment: @spajce I am not asking for a different solution. I am asking how to solve what I wrote. It is not in the duplicate list.

Comment: ok.. so, there's a simple solution from the link :)

Comment: which one you are suggesting? I am doing the same as the top answer and the rest two is little different. I am not wishing to write direct query. :)

Comment: if so.. why is that happen? :)

Comment: I think you're going to have to filter on your `table_type`, per: [Use SqlConnection.GetSchema to get Tables Only (No Views)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216564/use-sqlconnection-getschema-to-get-tables-only-no-views)

Answer (score 1):

I'd run a query like this rather than GetSchema:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: thanks, I know about that. but what is wrong with what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to only get Tables, then you will need to restrict schema. For `Table` there are four restrictions supported : (1)**Catalog**, (2)**Owner**, (3)**Table**, and (4)**TableType**.

```
GetSchema (string collectionName, string[] restrictionValues);
```

So you can write as:

```
var tables = sqlConn.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { null, null, null, "BASE TABLE" });
```

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-schema-collections. Quote: *"**TABLE_TYPE**, String, Type of table. Can be **VIEW** or **BASE TABLE**."*